# Seagate Slim Backup Plus HDD (2 TB) is not getting recognized by my System, but works fine in other Systems

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Well the issue started after i installed windows 7 on my system (Before this i had windows 10 where the HDD Worked fine), on a new Internal HDD(Seagate 2TB). My External 2TB HDD stopped getting recognized by the system. i thought it might be some issue with my installation process, so i re-installed windows 10 but still the issue exists. I tried Diskpart, Looking in Administration Tools, but as soon as i plug in the HDD all of them (Diskpart, Storage management, Device manager etc.) get Hanged/Stuck. The same HDD works fine in my Laptop and Android TV. I tried Seagate website for Drivers, i was not able to find any. What could be the issue, Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: How do you know they are Hanged/Stuck? How long did you wait?

Comment: Almost an hour, i was able to do other tasks in the system but these applications were still stalled

Comment: Is your Windows 7 fully patched using Windows Updates? Are there any errors in Device manager with or without the Seagate plugged in?